# python - discord.py how can I check if double quotes are in intput

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@commands.command()
async def test(self, ctx, text):
        if "\"" in text:
            await ctx.send("bad")
        if text == "ok":
            await ctx.send("ok")
        else:
            await ctx.send("no")
```

When member send `!submit askdsk` says `no` but if a double quote `"` is in input there is no output i tried to do `if "\"" in text:` but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: You can't use same string symbols like that. It starts and ends string! Inerpreter won't know what you want. You got 2 options.
using other string symbol `'"'` or formatting text  `a ="{}"; a.format('"')`. Second option also uses same input,but you can prepare more advanced strings that too.

Answer (score 1):

just make the check like this

```
if '"' in text:
```

quote the " in ' '